# Why is StoreDevtoolsModule in my production bundle, and how to remove it from there?

Tags: angular, ngrx

Using [webpack-bundle-analyzer](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-bundle-analyzer) I detected the module StoreDevtoolsModule into my production bundle.

I thought [three shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) would removed it, but it does not...

Is there a way to build in production mode without it? (it is not used anyway in production):

```js
(....)
//                \/ this one
import { StoreDevtoolsModule } from '@ngrx/store-devtools';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        (....),
        !environment.production ? StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument() : [],
        (....),
    ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: https://ngrx.io/guide/store-devtools/recipes/exclude

Comment: interesting that they maintain this obscured "recipes" tab in the docs, I think most people would miss it, like i did. Well the answer below is the same method as theirs, I will update to have this link there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After discussing the problem with my peers, we figured that the reason for it to be in the bundle is that because `environment.production` is evaluated at runtime, tree shaking will not remove the module from the bundle. Event though it is not really used.

There is a way around it though.

first create 2 files:

one to host the import array for non-prod (default), with the following contents

src/hat-trick/store-dev-tools-import.ts

```
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { StoreDevtoolsModule } from '@ngrx/store-devtools';

export const storeDevToolsImport = [
    !environment.production ? StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument() : []
];
```

and the other to host the import array for prod builds, with the following contents

src/hat-trick/store-dev-tools-import.prod.ts :

```
export const storeDevToolsImport = [];
```

add a `fileReplacements` section to your `angular.json` file at the production build config:

```
"production": {
 (....)
    "fileReplacements": [
        (....)
        {
            "replace": "src/hat-trick/store-dev-tools-import.ts",
            "with": "src/hat-trick/store-dev-tools-import.prod.ts"
        },
    ]
}
```

and finally, use the new variable `storeDevToolsImport` in you module, instead of importing `StoreDevtoolsModule` directly:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        (....),

        ...storeDevToolsImport,

        (....),
    ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And done! next time you build in prod mode, StoreDevtoolsModule will no longer be included (saving about 4kb)

NgRx docs have the same solution in a [hidden spot](https://ngrx.io/guide/store-devtools/recipes/exclude) as per comment on the question above

Answer (score 0):

It can be as simple as adding the following line.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    [... other imports]
    !environment.production ? StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
          name: 'overview',
          maxAge: 25,
        }) : [], // 
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: This does not work.... that is the exac problem my answer solves: tree shaking cannot remove the StoreDevtoolsModule because it's usage would be evaluated at run time.

Comment: The same piece of code with from my app.module. The only different is I have added option into `StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument`. Let me edit it.

Comment: you need to have a look on your bundled files (use  webpack-bundle-analyzer as per question) with this code in it. You will them easily verify that the StoreDevtoolsModule is there, and that your answer does not work as I pointed out... The `.instrument` options make no difference